# How to solve `Shopify node serve` - "curl is required for installing ngrok" error in Shopify-CLI?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, shopify, shopify-app

I am trying to start a development serve using shopify CLI using command
`shopify node serve` and I am getting an error which I have shown below...

[image: Error Photo]

Answer (score 0):

Turned Out that There was a missing path in System Environment Variables,
`%SystemRoot%\System32`. So I added it back and everything is working just fine.